# Refused business visitor but have Family visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, change-purpose-of-travel

I'm a post graduate doctor from Pakistan, want to pursue post graduate work in the UK. I read on Travel SE that the business visitor visa was being discontinued from 24 April 2015, I applied for it on 14th April 2015 and was refused. I need to go to the UK before June 17th to sit the PLAB 1 exam (there are no overseas centers hosting the exam in June so I cant sit it in Pakistan), I already have a family visit visa which expires in 2017, so what I wanted to know was can I possibly sit the Plab exam on my current visa (family visitor)?
Will they stop me at immigration services in light of the new rules ?

Answer (score 4):

On the 24th April 2015, the UK implemented new immigration rules which simplify visitor visas. Many different visa types were consolidated into the [new Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview), which allows business, tourism, family visits and [more](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). Existing visas of these types are treated the same as a Standard Visitor visa, so you can now do tourism and business on your old Family Visitor visa until it expires. Your application for a business visitor visa would have been refused because you already have a valid visa for the purpose: Taking the PLAB is explicitly allowed on the Standard Visitor visa, so you are fine to travel on your existing visa.

Comment: I would have expected if this were the case that the reasons for rejection would have said "You already have a valid visa for this purpose". @Dr Nabeel Khan, does it?

Comment: I was told that I did not have enough supporting documents I.e. my father's bank statements.

Comment: That's very strange. Did they cancel your existing visa, then?

Comment: No they did not ......